# Should I expect worklight to create armeabi-v7a directory in Android project?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

For a project I'm working on, we need to have an .so file submitted to the apps/[app]/android/native/libs/armeabi-v7a directory.  When I did this, though, I got class not found errors... realized I need other libraries in armeabi-v7a similar to the libraries that Worklight puts in the armeabi directory (e.g. libopenssl_fips).

Should I "simply" copy those myself from apps/[app]/android/native/libs/armeabi to apps/[app]/android/native/libs/armeabi-v7a?  Or is there something different I should be doing so that WL builds the apps/[app]/android/native/libs/armeabi-v7a directory with those libraries (e.g. libopenssl_fips) inside it?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: I don't know anything about Worklight, but if Worklight puts `.so` files in the `armeabi` directory, why not leave them alone? They will be used on ARM v7 devices just fine.

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should place those files on your own in the location you've specified. Worklight will not do that.